# Android inapp camera and video capture

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, video-capture

I am trying to implement an in-app camera to my application, which will allow me to take either a still photo or a video, with the result being stored in a variable.

So basically the top tabs (HOME, GALLERY, CAMERA, EFFECTS) are all `Fragments`. Assuming we are currently on the "CAMERA" tab, inside this view you will have two further tabs at the bottom one for taking still shots and the other for video, the rest of the screen should be taken up by a camera interface showing the cameras view.

The Android developer documentation mainly talks about using androids built in camera and then saving the result in one of my own variables, which I dont want to do.

**Resouces I have taken a look at**

- Android developer documentation
- Random Google tutorials & stackoverflow
- Android arsenal and 3rd party created libraries.
- `Material Camera` looks good but as soon as I try and add its dependancy to my app, the build `gradle` throws an error, so that one doesn't work.
- `CWAC-Cam2` looks really complicated, I don't understand how to implement it.

Comment: "with the result being stored in a variable" that will not be possible. Storing a video in a variable would require a huge amount of memory, you'll need to store it in a file.

Comment: I do not mind how it's stored, as long as I can access it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the resource you couldn't find: [Using Camera inside app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Basically for taking photo you'll need to access the camera resource through:

```
Camera.open()
```

Then create a class for showing the preview like the following:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

For capturing you'll need a `PictureCallback`.

For video recording checkt the first source at the `Capturing videos` section; there you'll need a `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: I'll take a look at this thanks, how hard is it to implement both camera and video?

Comment: It'll take some time. Also some device testing is needed as on emulator it's hard to check whether the camera is ok.

Comment: If the answer helped you, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: The documentation section you provided - does that tell me exactly how to create the whole camera app?